# chmod not assigning permissions properly?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, chmod

We are testing osTicket which is an open source ticketing system and have set everything up, but when we try to connect to the page we get blank results with the following error logs:

```
 [:error] [pid 1742] [client 192.168.71.167:47164] PHP Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

 [:error] [pid 1742] [client 192.168.71.167:47164] PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/osticket/setup/index.php'(include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Assuming permission denied means that I don't have access to open a certain file I looked through the permissions set on the files.

I noticed that I had no permissions whatsoever on index.php and went ahead and set it with `chmod 755 index.php`. It still doesn't work! Instead of being assigned drwxr-xr-x it was set to -rwxr-xr-x. Why is the d missing?

Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The leading `d` isn't part of the permissions string: it would denote that the target is a directory rather than a plain file (which index.php presumably isn't). You can't "assign" `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d` refers to directories (folders).  Your `index.php` file is not a directory, it is a file.  Therefore, you should not see the `d`.